# .NET MAUI CollectionView: Items with different height

Tags: maui

When using a CollectionView in my MAUI app, it seems every row is forced to have the same height, no matter what I try to do to force it to do otherwise.

I have a DataTemplate for my items that has a variable HeightRequest based upon the ItemType, but this HeightRequest for every row seems to be set to the same height as the first row. Is what I'm trying to do even possible with a CollectionView? Or is there a different control I can use to display a collection of generic items that will allow me to accomplish this behavior?

I can share more of my code if that would be helpful, currently I just want to know if this approach is even feasible.

I have tried using a variety of different layout items, GridItemsLayout, LinearItemsLayout, as well as trying to extend my own custom versions of IItemsLayout without any luck.

I've also tried switching from using a CollectionView to a variety of other controls, such as ListView, SelectableItemsView... The closest thing I can find to do what I want is to use a CarouselView with a vertical layout, but I'm not sure that's necessarily the best control for my use case because it seems like that control is designed to only display one item at a time.

**Edit: Here is a snippet of code that reproduces my issue. I've noticed that it works as expected on Android, but not on Windows.**

### MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:OrientationToHeightConverter x:Key="OrientationToHeightConverter"/>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextEditTemplate">
                <StackLayout Orientation="{Binding Orientation}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Label}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Margin="4"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"  Margin="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Orientation, Converter={StaticResource OrientationToHeightConverter}}">
                    </Entry>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TextEditTemplate}"/>

</ContentPage>
```

### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Controls.Add(new TextEditControl() { Label = "Title", Text = "Item title" });
        Controls.Add(new TextEditControl() { Label = "Description", Text = "Item description", Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical });
        Controls.Add(new TextEditControl() { Label = "Description", Text = "Item description", Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical });
        Controls.Add(new TextEditControl() { Label = "Description", Text = "Item description", Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TextEditControl> Controls { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TextEditControl>();
}

public class OrientationToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is StackOrientation orientation)
        {
            if (orientation == StackOrientation.Vertical)
            {
                return 200;
            }
        }

        return 40;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TextEditControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(TextEditControl), string.Empty);
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Label), typeof(string), typeof(TextEditControl), string.Empty);

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty OrientationProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OrientationProperty), typeof(StackOrientation), typeof(TextEditControl), StackOrientation.Horizontal);

    public StackOrientation Orientation
    {
        get { return (StackOrientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0#item-sizing

Comment: Please show the relevant code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What did you set as the `ItemSizingStrategy` of the *CollectionView*? Which platforms did you test this on?

Comment: I set `ItemSizingStrategy` to "MeasureAllItems" which is also apparently the default value. Seems like it should work based on my understanding of the documentation, but it doesn't work correctly on Windows.